# Friend functions and namespaces. Cannot access private member in class

Tags: c++, class, templates, friend

So I have a `class` inside a `foo` namespace, which includes a `friend` function. Now I want the definition of the `friend` function to be in a different namespace `bar` so it can be called the way you see below. The error I get is that the private member `val` cannot be accessed.

**Question:** Why?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo 
{
    template<typename T>
    class myclass
    {
    private:
        T val;
    public:
        myclass(T v) : val(v) {}

        template<class U>
        friend void myfun(myclass<U>);
    };

    namespace bar 
    {
        template<class U>
        void myfun(myclass<U> a)
        {
            std::cout << a.val;
        }
    } //bar
} //foo

int main()
{
    foo::myclass<int> a(5);
    foo::bar::myfun(a);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare `foo::bar::myfun` before the friend declaration and use appropriate namespace qualification (`bar::`):

```
namespace foo 
{
    template<typename T>
    class myclass;

    namespace bar 
    {
        template<class U>
        void myfun(myclass<U> a);
    } //bar

    template<typename T>
    class myclass
    {
    private:
        T val;
    public:
        myclass(T v) : val(v) {}

        template<class U>
        friend void bar::myfun(myclass<U>);
    };

} //foo
```

Otherwise another function called `myfun` will be declared in the `foo` namespace by the friend declaration.